# Gatsby with Wordpress - inner page link wont form correctly

Tags: wordpress, gatsby

I am attempting to use gatsby with WordPress. I am experimenting with starters available on the gatsby site.

1. Gatsby Develop is running without error. It is fetching all posts etc correctly.
2. But when I load the site only home page load right,
   inner pages takes me to some URL as
   `http://0.0.7.227/10/15/what-is-the-issue/`.
3. The home page is listing all the content and pagination works as well.

**The wordpress source config:**

```
{
  "baseUrl": "dev-somename.pantheonsite.io",
  "protocol": "http",
  "hostingWPCOM": false,
  "useACF": false,
  "includedRoutes": [
    "**/*/*/categories",
    "**/*/*/posts",
    "**/*/*/pages",
    "**/*/*/media",
    "**/*/*/tags",
    "**/*/*/taxonomies",
    "**/*/*/users"
  ]
}
```

**Last part of my terminal output.**

```
success run queries - 40.874s - 2243/2244 54.90/s
success Generating image thumbnails - 41.515s - 7/7 0.17/s
⠀
You can now view gatsby-wordpress-libre-starter in the browser.
⠀
  http://localhost:8000/
⠀
View GraphiQL, an in-browser IDE, to explore your site's data and schema
⠀
  http://localhost:8000/___graphql
⠀
Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use gatsby build
⠀
success Building development bundle - 5.957s
```

Can't figure out what to do next.